# In Zend-Framewok plugin, how to do somthing simular to $this->view->foo =...;?

Tags: php, zend-framework

i wrote a small plugin, so i will be able to get the name of the controller in each view.
but idk how to "pass" a parameter to the view (do sumth like $this->view->foo =...;).

```
class Zend_Extension_Controller_Plugin_GetControllerName extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $this->view->controllerName = $request->getControllerName();
    }
}
```

what can i write instead of $this->view->controllerName so it will work?

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361736/zend-framework-detecting-wich-controller-or-page-you-are-using-are-on/3361785#3361785

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$view->controllerName = $request->getControllerName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helper broker to get an instance of the view. Something like this should work:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('ViewRenderer')->view->foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: it tells Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::getScriptPaths() in C:\wamp\www\OutOfScopes\OutOfScopes\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php on line 489

what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Take this example as basis:

```
class Plugin_Sidebar extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if($request->getModuleName() == 'admin')
        {
            return;
        }

        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
        if (null === $viewRenderer->view) {
            $viewRenderer->initView();
        }
        $view = $viewRenderer->view;


        $Categories = new Model_DbTable_Categories();
        $view->menuItens = $Categories->getMenu();

    }
}
```